# wso2mb 100% cpu usage after message submit

Tags: wso2, mq, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I want to try out an WSO2MB (Message Broker) (version 2.2.0) implementation, but as soon as I put a message on the queue (via an WSO2ESB message store) the CPU of message broker goes to 100% and only comes down again after purging the queue and restarting MB. 
Is this a know issue to anyone?

If I cannot solve this, I would need to change MB for Apache ActiveMQ, but that would be such a waste of time when I would like to have all products of one supplier: WSO2...

Comment: I dropped back to version 2.1.1 - that did not have this behaviour. Probably there is still a bug in 2.2.0.

Comment: Bug still exists in MB-3.1.0 when shutting down the ESB-5.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in MB 3.2.0 You can get it as a part of wso2 [enterprise integrator](http://wso2.com/integration). Just run the broker.sh in bin folder. Default AMQP ports will be offset by 3.